# Haskell mutliline guard inside do not working

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming, guard

Hello I am new to Haskell and I think that my problem is simple but important for me.

This works:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
    inp <- getLine
    let output i | odd i = "Alice" | even i = "Bob" | otherwise = "Weird"
    putStrLn (output (read inp))
```

This does not work

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
    inp <- getLine
    let output i 
        | odd i = "Alice" 
        | even i = "Bob" 
        | otherwise = "Weird"
    putStrLn (output (read inp))
```

What I know:
Inside do you write "lets" or "let" before every function you declare and you do not write "in". Also when I wrote output as a non local function it worked.

What have I missunderstood?

edit:
would you recommend writing like this?

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
    inp <- getLine
    let
        output i 
            | odd i = "Alice" 
            | even i = "Bob"
    putStrLn (output (read inp))
```

Comment: You should indent the guards, so at least one space more than `output`.

Comment: Are they not indented already? They are 4 spaces further in than output

Comment: no, right now they are at the `let` level, so they have the same indentation as `output`. Since the guards "belong" to the `output` function, you need to indent these more than `output`.

Comment: Your last edit is fine. You can put `let output i` together on the first line, if you prefer. If you use the `output` function only on `inp`, you can remove the argument `i` and use `inp` directly. I'd strongly recommend ending with `otherwise` instead of `even i`. Also, turn on warnings with `-Wall` during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent the guards (with at least one extra space compared to the position of `output`), for example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    inp <- getLine
    let output i 
            | odd i = "Alice" 
            | even i = "Bob" 
            | otherwise = "Weird"
    putStrLn (output (read inp))
```

Since a number is either `odd` or `even`, you can just use `otherwise` for the `even` case:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    inp <- getLine
    let output i 
            | odd i = "Alice" 
            | otherwise = "Bob"
    putStrLn (output (read inp))
```

Comment: Perfect! Is this the way you would recommend writing this? Also I wonder that "otherwise" case should never happend and I can run the code without it but is that considered bad practise?

Comment: @IlDeSanta: since a number is either `odd` or `even`, you can use `otherwise` for the second guard.

Comment: Yes that is true I had it because I want the code to be easily read altough here it is very obvious. But more overall is it recommended to end the guard with something that is always true?

Comment: @IlDaSanta: I personally prefer that, since that guarantees that each input maps on output (and non-total functions are typically not good practice ihmo).

Comment: Also how I did after the edit because I got a bit less confused is that good or bad practise?

Comment: @IlDeSanta: I would prefer `otherwise` over the `even i`, since it requires less brain cycles to ensure that all input eventually will trigger a guard.

Comment: I meant writing otherwise below let indended 4 steps because writing it besides let seems to be equivalent to indenting 4 spaces.

Comment: @IlDeSanta: well if you write it besides, that is the same as writing it with a new line. The indentation is necessary for the compiler to group the new lines under the `output i` part.

Comment: If the guards cover the space but it is anything less than dead-obvious, I like to use `| otherwise = error "impossible"`. I've caught a few bugs that way. You don't just want every input to map to any output, you want the correct output.